# Minecraft: Villagers Steal?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I play Minecraft PE and I try to have the Villagers do the work, but they don't give the crops back. Can they put it in a chest or hopper?

Comment: AFAIK they just store them in own inventory... which is similarly sized to yours. With most crops stacking to 64, it would take years till that overflows. The way around that was getting them to pick a wide variety of items so that they fill up the slots. Not sure if that still works.

Answer (score 2):

You can make them attempt to throw it at another villager. Do this by trapping a villager (Preferably not a farmer) in a glass cell. Dig a one block wide trench all around the cell. Place a hopper two blocks out from the center of the cell and level with the ground.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbuTV.jpg) Then, link up the hopper to a chest and wait. Also, punch a 1 block hole at head level so that any villagers attempting to throw their crops see the trapped villager.
Finished product:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29mo9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, they don’t.This is why I would suggest trapping them all in a hole, or just kill them. Also the only way they can plant back the seed is if they have a seed in their “inventory”.