# Do villagers take items from chests in 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building my base near a village. I am keeping my chests with valuables in my house. I have a doubt whether the villagers can steal my belongings from my chest.

*I have checked [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/328008/minecraft-villagers-steal) but it's for the wrong version and doesn't really answer my question either.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Villagers don't take items from any containers - even ones that are their workstations. The only exception is farmer composting plants in his composter and taking the bonemeal it produces. But chests, barrels, smokers, blast furnaces etc are safe.

Comment: I am waiting for more answers with sources mentioned. If none are available I will accept this answer.

Comment: @DarkPhoenix It's pretty hard to find sources proving the negative - there's too many things villagers *don't do* to list all. Villagers never took anything out of containers in vanilla MC, not before the 1.14 overhaul and not after. There are mods that change that, e.g [TekTopia](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/tektopia) overhauling village mechanics, including 'community chests' where villagers deposit their products and take resources they need.

Comment: @DarkPhoenix ive played minecraft for years and years and always used to build my houses in villages, and i can say that ive never had villagers ever take/add stuff